# Assigning a number sequence for groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, lambda, group-by, sequence

Create a Sequence in new column which is groupby tag_id & sub_id and ascending sort dataframe by tag_id and logdate. Expected Output is shown in the below image.

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'tag_id': [496976, 496976, 603100, 603100, 715078, 715078, 978924, 978924, 1276120, 1276120, 1276120],
                    'sub_id' :['W00-8748', 'A00-1012', 'A00-4028', 'A00-4028', 'W00-0706', 
                               'W00-1960', 'W00-1066', 'W00-6462', 'W00-1397', 'W00-1427', 'W00-6727'],
                    'log_date':['2012-06-28','2013-06-28','2016-02-18','2016-02-18','2008-02-25','2008-09-28','2008-04-28','2010-10-20','2008-07-10','2008-07-15','2008-07-15']})
dfx = dfx.sort_values(by=['tag_id','log_date'],ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
dfx
```

**Expected Output**

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: For clarity, can you confirm that the 3rd and 4th rows have the same values because they are duplicated? Also, what should be the Seq if there was a row inserted after the 4th with the same tag_id but a different log_date?

Comment: Yes its duplicate , tag_id & sub_id should be unique . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and subtract the [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) of duplicated values:

```
df['Seq'] = (dfx.groupby('tag_id').cumcount().add(1)
            -dfx.duplicated().groupby(dfx['tag_id']).cumsum()
            )
```

Which you can make more efficient by pre-assigning the duplicated status (and avoid recomputing the `groupby` twice):

```
g = dfx.assign(d=dfx.duplicated()).groupby('tag_id')

dfx['Seq'] = g.cumcount().add(1) - g['d'].cumsum()
```

Another alternative with a nested `groupby` (less efficient):

```
dfx['Seq'] = (dfx.groupby('tag_id', group_keys=False)
                 .apply(lambda g: g.groupby(['sub_id', 'log_date'],
                                            sort=False)
                                   .ngroup().add(1))
             )
```

Output:

```
     tag_id    sub_id    log_date  Seq
0    496976  W00-8748  2012-06-28    1
1    496976  A00-1012  2013-06-28    2
2    603100  A00-4028  2016-02-18    1
3    603100  A00-4028  2016-02-18    1
4    715078  W00-0706  2008-02-25    1
5    715078  W00-1960  2008-09-28    2
6    978924  W00-1066  2008-04-28    1
7    978924  W00-6462  2010-10-20    2
8   1276120  W00-1397  2008-07-10    1
9   1276120  W00-1427  2008-07-15    2
10  1276120  W00-6727  2008-07-15    3
```

Intermediates:

```
     tag_id    sub_id    log_date  Seq  cumcount  duplicated_cumsum
0    496976  W00-8748  2012-06-28    1         1                  0
1    496976  A00-1012  2013-06-28    2         2                  0
2    603100  A00-4028  2016-02-18    1         1                  0
3    603100  A00-4028  2016-02-18    1         2                  1
4    715078  W00-0706  2008-02-25    1         1                  0
5    715078  W00-1960  2008-09-28    2         2                  0
6    978924  W00-1066  2008-04-28    1         1                  0
7    978924  W00-6462  2010-10-20    2         2                  0
8   1276120  W00-1397  2008-07-10    1         1                  0
9   1276120  W00-1427  2008-07-15    2         2                  0
10  1276120  W00-6727  2008-07-15    3         3                  0
```